# Laravel triple hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel, has-many-through

Hello I'm trying to get count of all replies.

```
$forum->sections->topics->replies->count();
```

It's possible to make something like this?

```
// Forum Model

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Reply', 'App\Topic', 'App\Section');
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Can't you simple build all of those relations and do:

    `$data = Forum::with('reply.topic.section')->get();`

?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? I'ts not something possible unless you go into some foreach loops, but still, it will take a lot of resources from your system to do that if you have a big system..